# Как на Java записать символы валют в CSV файл для корректного импорта в Excel

Tags: java, excel, csv

При импорте получившегося CSV файла в Excel знаки валют, кроме `€` и `$` заменяются на `?`. В Notepad++ все отображается нормально.

```
String data = "$,€,₪,₴,zł,kr,£,..."

String fileName = "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\apache-tomcat-7.0.68\\temp\\testCSV.csv";

String uncode = "UTF-8";

//uncode = "UTF-8", "UTF-16", "UTF-16BE", "UTF-16LE", "Cp866", "Cp1251", "US-ASCII", "ISO-8859-1";
```

Пробовал разные варианты:

1. `FileWriter out = new FileWriter(fileName);`
2. `OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(fileName),uncode);`
3. `PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(fileName, uncode));`
4. `PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter (new OutputStreamWriter (new FileOutputStream (fileName), uncode));`
5. `Writer out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(fileName), uncode));`
6. :

   ```
   File f = new File(fileName);
   FileUtils.writeStringToFile(f, data, uncode);
   out.append(data);
   //out.write(data); //out.println(data);
   ```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Как вы потом получившийся файл просматриваете? Так-то все способы, кроме первого, должны работать. Еще может быть мнение компилятора о кодировке исходника не совпадает с вашим.

Comment: Открываю в Microsoft Excel. Что правда, если открыть в "Notepad++" то символы отображаются верно.

Comment: вроде в экселе при импорте csv можно выбрать кодировку

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я могу ошибаться, но насколько помню, MS Excel не распознает UTF-8 без [BOM](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2) (Byte Order Mark), т.ч. попробуйте как-то так:

```
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("file.txt", true), "utf8"));
writer.append('\uFEFF');
writer.append("мама мыла раму");
```

**Проверка**

```
» /usr/bin/printf "\ufeff...\n" | file file.txt
file.txt: UTF-8 Unicode (with BOM) text, with no line terminators
```

В то же время, большинству текстовых редакторов BOM не интересен, поэтому в них у вас текст отображается нормально.

Comment: Спасибо. Помогло добавление `writer.append('\uFEFF');`.